# Intercept or Read Windows push notifications

Tags: windows, push-notification, notifications

I have some 3rd party applications (not owned by me) which send notifications on my windows laptop. Is there a way that I can programmatically read the notifications in my action center (right pane in windows)? I want to read the content of the push notification and do some processing over the content of the notifications.